# Why is my function not being executed in python?

Tags: python, function, variables

```
def a():
    x=20
    def b():
        global x
        x=88
        print("before calling b",x)
        b()
        print("after calling b",x) 
a()
```

My code is showing no error while debugging but when I run it, it shows no output. It is not getting the function.

Comment: you don't want to call `b()`?

Comment: Is the code you see in the post indentend **100%** like yours ?

Answer (score 2):

In the above code you call the function `a` which creates and sets a local variable `x` and defines a nested function, but that function is never called. As such you do not see any prints.

Note that just calling `b()` in `a` is not a good idea - as this function will recursively call itself with no stop condition. Instead you could write it as follows:

```
def a():
    x=20

    def b():
        global x
        x=88


    print("before calling b", x)
    b()
    print("after calling b", x)
a()
```

Comment: This looks just like a comment

Comment: @azro This is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really **want** is this code:

```
def a():
    x=20

    def b():
        global x
        x=88

    print("before calling b",x)
    b()
    print("after calling b",x)

a()
```

This code tests the effect of calling `b` from within `a` on the values of a variable `x`, local to `a`. There will be no effect, as `x` is not global. The output would be:

```
before calling b 20
after calling b 20
```

If you change the definition of `b` to:

```
def b():
    nonlocal x
    x=88
```

You will see the effect of modifying `x`:

```
before calling b 20
after calling b 88
```